# Is it secure to activate logout form from outside the form itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First question on StackOverflow, so pardon me if this is a duplicate (I did search first, I promise).

I'm building a simple back office application using ASP.NET MVC 4.  The default code for logging out uses a form in order to use the validation feature, like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```

However, this leaves me with some weird styling issues with my navigation bar.  It occurred to me that I could workaround it easily by just moving the link outside of the form, like so:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log Out</a>
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

However, this leaves me wondering: **Is this still secure?**

(I think it is, but I'm new to ASP.NET so I wanted to get confirmation.)

Comment: why do you think this is insecure?

Comment: My impression was that the AntiForgeryToken needed to precede the sensitive code (i.e. the link itself), but that didn't make sense because all the link is doing is posting the form.  Posting/routing is the part that needs to be protected, so as long as the AntiForgeryToken is there, it should be fine.

This, however, is my first foray into building a more serious (read: not entirely client-side) web application, and I don't want to royally botch the security of it by being "clever".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine if `LogOut` method only accepts POST requests and you validate the antiforgery token.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    //log out user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I assuming the page submits as you would like it to.

The forms security is more about the context of how your submitting the data. If it needs to be secure then you may need to consider some from of internal system encrytion or SSL certificate.

Comment: I am using SSL for this, but as I understand it, that doesn't prevent the cross-site scripting issues that the AntiForgeryToken is protecting against.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to fix the "weird styling issues with my navigation bar" rather than hack about with HTML elements like that.

Post the HTML if you'd like help.

By the way, I think the anti-forgery token would work with what you've posted.

Comment: I would agree with you, but I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for the first time (with their base navigation bar).  I don't have a lot of time to study/learn the code to modify it (very tight deadline), so I'm trying to use it as is for now.

Comment: Ok, well basically the javascript is submitting the form so I don't see the form itself being insecure.